# Touchpad right click doesn't work in the new version 18.04.1

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, lenovo, click-policy

since i upgraded my version to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the right click doesn't work.
(i have  Lenovo Yoga 500-15ISK)
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing "gnome tweaks" from Ubuntu software? And then "keyboard & mouse" tab and then "mouse click emulation" tab and then selecting "Area" tab??

Comment: still don't working :(

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of above screen? Gnome Tweaks-keyboard and mouse-mouse click emulation-Area..

Comment: I experienced clicking just right click didn't worked for me many times..try to click as corner as possible lower right corner and see..

Comment: clicking the lower right corner worked?